# Laravel 6 - One Controller with Multiple Functions

Tags: php, laravel

I have `multiple users` in my system, so I want a manager User with different `dashboard`.

**`My Controller look like this:`**

```
-Dashboard
 ->AdminDashboardController
 ->UserDashboardController
```

**In my AdminDashboardController** I have 2 function

```
    public function countAllUser()
    {
        $cards = User::count();

        return response()->json(['cards' => $cards]);
    }

    public function totalSales()
    {
        return 'Hello';
    }
```

**`And In My DashboardController Like this`**

```
  public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $adminUser = auth()->user()->roles->pluck('name')->toArray();

        if($adminUser[0] === 'administrator') {
            return (new AdminDashboardController())->countAllUser();
        }
    }
```

yes, its work, but if I tried something like this

`return (new AdminDashboardController())->countAllUser()->totalSales()`;

It doesn't work and I think this doesn't make sense either..

Is there a way I can achieve this?? Thanks...

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish. what does `return (new AdminDashboardController())->countAllUser()->totalSales();` supposed to return?

Comment: @ryantxr i want to return multiple `functions` in `index` in `DashboardController`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should create Action/Helper/Service Class but if you want to return controller methods you will need to do something like

```
return response([
    'user_count' => (new AdminDashboardController())->countAllUser(), 
    'sales' => (new AdminDashboardController())->totalSales(),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although call controller method from another controller is not a good practice ,you should use service.

But if you really want to do this , you can do it by

```
\App::call('App\Http\Controllers\AdminDashboardController@countAllUser');
```

or

```
(new AdminDashboardController())->countAllUser();
```

or

```
app(\App\Http\Controllers\AdminDashboardController::class)->countAllUser();
```

Your code

```
return (new AdminDashboardController())->countAllUser()->totalSales();
```

didn't work because 
`(new AdminDashboardController())->countAllUser()` returns a `\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse` instance , you should call `totalSales` on an controller instance

Comment: He has to use getter and setters, and also have to know encapsulation